# ASP.NET Core how to display images from www/images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.Net Core and I have images in `wwwroot/images` dir and I want to display the images when i clicked them. I made a View page to view all the images (and data as well) and when i clicked the images it will go to the detail pages.

Here is the detail page without images displaying.

[image]

and here is when the full path of images `https://localhost:44325/Catelog/Details/images/book2.jpg`

All my images are in `wwwroot/images` dir.

[image]

Details.cshtml

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <img src="@Model.imageUrl" class="detailImage" />
        </div>
 </div>
```

So how can I show my images or say how do `wwwroot/images` share its resources (maybe ?)

Comment: Are you sure that the URL isn't https://localhost:44325/images/book2.jpg ?
It looks like the images folder is sitting directly under your wwwroot folder, so the controller and action names shouldn't be necessary

Comment: @Jack localhost:44325/images/book2.jpg this show image but why the detail page doesnt show...

Comment: You'll need to make sure that model.imageURL equals that path: "/images/book2.jpg"
If it is something like "/Catelog/Details/images/book2.jpg" then the image won't show, because that's not actually where the file is on the web server

Comment: how to make the imageURl as the path u mentioned??

Comment: Well, where is the image URL coming from? I assume you are getting it from a database somewhere?

Comment: yeah.. mssql database and i link them with EF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211257/discussion-between-jack-and-kopi-bryant).

Comment: add (  app.UseStaticFiles();  ) to your startup file in public void Configure

Comment: @mhkarami97 yeah.. i already have it

Comment: The url should be:`https://localhost:44325/images/book2.jpg`

Comment: @Rena yea i know it. but how i do it ?

Comment: Save `/images/book2.jpg` to your `imageUrl`.

Comment: @Rena yeah.. it is actually save as `images/book2.jpg` in my MSSQL Database already

Comment: @Rena What to do if the application is running from a subdirectory on server? E.g - https://domain/folder/images/book.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you model.imageURL equals that:

```
images/book2.jpg
```

just add / before @Model.imageUrl like :

```
<img src="/@Model.imageUrl" class="detailImage" />
```

If it's like :

```
book2.jpg
```

change code like this:

```
<img src="/images/@Model.imageUrl" class="detailImage" />
```

Comment: Wow. It works .. Thank you. but could you explain why adding a single "slash" make it work please.

Comment: @KopiBryant Add single slash means that you want to start directory from base : https://localhost:44325 , if you don't add slash , imageUrl just add directory that you are there : https://localhost:44325/Catelog/Details/